# How can I best log a failed cast in Swift?

Tags: swift

How do I log that casting failed in an elegant way? Ideally I'd love to do something like what follows but since extending `Any` isn't possible I'm at a loss. I'm also not aware of a way to cast using an assigned type (ex. `String.self`) so that's two problems.

```
let actuallyADouble: Any = 3.0
let stringType = String.self
guard let anyToString = actuallyADouble as? stringType else {
    actuallyADouble.logFailedCast(to: stringType)
    return
}
setString(anyToString) // will never reach
```

For bonus points, what would be even more *magical* would be a way to extend all casting, so I could just do the following and a log occurs outside this scope on failure:

```
guard let anyToString = actuallyADouble as? stringType else { return }
```

---

**Background:**

We have a Swift project that didn't enforce the practice of avoiding force-casts, so there are lots of things like this:

```
let anyToString = actuallyADouble as! String
```

We are refactoring to this safer code:

```
guard let anyToString = actuallyADouble as? String else { return }
```

Now our app won't crash, but instead we'll just continue operation like nothing is wrong, potentially making troubleshooting more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, extending `Any` isn't possible. But optionals hold whatever, and if you rely on them, you can get your logging and have very similar code to what you're already using.

```swift
extension Optional {
  struct UnwrapError: Error { }

  static func unwrap(_ any: Any) throws -> Wrapped {
    guard let wrapped = any as? Wrapped else {
      print("\(any) cannot be cast to \(Wrapped.self)")
      throw UnwrapError()
    }

    return wrapped
  }
}
```

```swift
try Double?.unwrap(actuallyADouble) // 3
let double: Double = try Optional.unwrap(actuallyADouble) // 3
try? String?.unwrap(actuallyADouble) // nil. "3.0 cannot be cast to String"
```

…or even just

```swift
extension Optional {
  init(_ any: Any) {
    self = any as? Wrapped
    if self == nil {
      print("\(any) cannot be cast to \(Wrapped.self)")
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
Double?(actuallyADouble) // 3
String?(actuallyADouble) // nil. "3.0 cannot be cast to String"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a free function like:

```
func loggedCast<A, B>(_ input: A, to: B.Type) -> B? {
    if let casted = input as? B {
        return casted
    }
    else {
        // Log however you want
        print("Failed to cast \(String(describing: input)) to type \(B.self)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Which you can use like:

```
let actuallyADouble: Any = 3.0
guard let anyToString = loggedCast(actuallyADouble, to: String.self) else { return }
```

Unfortunately, you can't get rid the of the `guard let ___ = ... else { return }` boilerplate, because control flow is explicit, and you can't make a caller function return from a callee function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with on my own. It absolutely works but I feel like there's a better way:

```
func DLogFailedCast<T>(object: T, desiredType: Any.Type) {
    let message = "CAST FAILURE: \(type(of: object)) to \(desiredType)"
    let log = OSLog(subsystem: "com.company.example", category: "Failed Cast")
    os_log("%@", log: log, type: .debug, message)
}
```

Usage:

```
let actuallyADouble: Any = 3.0
guard let anyToString = actuallyADouble as? String else {
    DLogFailedCast(object: actuallyADouble, desiredType: String.self)
    return
}
setString(anyToString)
```